# Continuous addition calculator (js + html)

Tags: html

This is a Continuous addition
calculator

I am trying to fix it so it doesn't say error

But still it does not run （no move in the page)

If anyone answers this question thank you very much

https://codepen.io/ejptbzpi-the-animator/pen/eYbdqWL

When I use js  in other file it runs but why does it not run in html

```js
document.getElementById('cn').
onclick = function() {

  var mo_m =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('mo_m').value);

  ////the got multiplication is (mo_m)

  var mo_s =
    parseInt(document.getElementById('mo_s').value);

  /// for multiplication use (mo_s)

  console.log = (...e) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById("log").innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]) : e[i]) + "<br />"
    }
  };

  var tim_in = 1;
  var tim_on = 0;
  var cn_a = 0;
  var cn_a = mo_m;

  var tim_of =
    `
第零刻 第零次 第一番：<br>
${mo_m}
`

  function cn(mo_m, mo_s) {
    while (tim_in <= mo_s) {
      tim_in++;
      tim_on++;
      var cn_f = cn_a;
      var cn_a = cn_a + mo_m;
      console.log("第" + tim_on + "次（第" + tim_in + "番)<br>" + cn_f + " + " + mo_m + " = " + cn_a + "<br><br>")
    }

    cn(mo_m, mo_s)
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>方程部落：乘法</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>出題</h1>
  <br> 被算數
  <input type="number" id='mo_m'>
  <br> 致算數
  <input type="number" id='mo_s'>
  <br>


  <h1>運算過程</h1>
  <hr>
  <button id='cn'>乘法</button>
  <br>
  <p id="log"></p>
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <br>
  <hr>

  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where do you include your JS? You need `<script src="calculator.js"></script>` and the calculator.js has the javascript in a file in the same folder as the HTML

Comment: It would be easier if you changed the snippet I made you to use English so we know what to enter and where to click. At least use better variables

Comment: thx you my english speak really need grow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never terminate the recursive function.

Here is an updated script. I changed to use addEventListener and use a load event so you can externalise the js file

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const mo_mField = document.getElementById('mo_m');
  const mo_sField = document.getElementById('mo_s');
  const log = document.getElementById("log");
  document.getElementById('cn').addEventListener('click', () => {

    var mo_m = +mo_mField.value;
    var mo_s = +mo_sField.value;

    console.log = (...e) => {
      for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        log.innerHTML += (typeof(e[i]) == "object" ? JSON.stringify(e[i]) : e[i]) + "<br />";
      }
    };

    var tim_in = 1;
    var tim_on = 0;
    var cn_a = mo_m;

    //(Moment zero, Time zero, First time)
    var tim_of = `第零刻 第零次 第一番：<br>${mo_m}`;

    const cn = (mo_m, mo_s) => {
      // Termination condition for recursive function
      if (tim_in > mo_s) return;

      tim_in++;
      tim_on++;
      var cn_f = cn_a;
      cn_a = cn_a + mo_m;

      // 第 n 次（第 n 番) (The nth time)
      console.log(`第${tim_on}次（第${tim_in}番)<br>${cn_f} + ${mo_m} = ${cn_a}`);

      cn(mo_m, mo_s);
    };

    cn(mo_m, mo_s);


  });
});
```

```html
<h1>Set Questions</h1>
<br> Multiplicand
<input type="number" id='mo_m'>
<br> Multiplier
<input type="number" id='mo_s'>
<br>

<h1>Calculation Process</h1>
<hr>
<button id='cn'>Multiplication</button>
<br>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: very thanks you now i got it